# Modify input on keydown event

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I would like to modify user input as they are typing in a textarea, for auto-completion purposes. For example, if the user type <kbd>(</kbd>, then add a <kbd>)</kbd> so the user gets <kbd>()</kbd>, just by pressing <kbd>(</kbd>.
I tried to achieve this by listening to the `keydown` event on the input, but I can't do the modifications synchronously, as the `value` property of the `input` element is not immediately updated. I think that's because of the event bubbling. The only solution I found or the moment is waiting something like 10ms before updating the input, but is there a proper way to do it?

Comment: The [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event is triggered after the textarea has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `keyup` event instead `keydown`.

Answer (score 0):

This keyHandler will add a ")" for every "(" typed in a text field with the class `.txt` (easily changed on line 2). The caret will be in between the newest set of parenthesis.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Bind window to the keydown event
window.onkeydown = autoChar;
/*
Event handler passes Event Object by default
Reference the tag the user interacted with
*//*
If user hit the '(' key AND the user interacted with a .txt...
...define variables for .txt.value, and selectionStart/End...
...reassign .txt.value with a ')' at the end...
...focus() on .txt...
...setSelectionRange on .txt
*/
function autoChar(e) {
  const text = e.target;
  if (e.key == '(' && text.matches('.txt')) {
    let string = text.value;
    let start = text.selectionStart;
    let end = text.selectionEnd + 1;
    text.value = string.slice(0, end) + ')';
    text.focus();
    let position = start;
    text.setSelectionRange(position, position);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class='txt'><br>
  <input><br>
  <textarea class='txt'></textarea>
</form>
```